# How can I write an English document with a few words of Thai, Japanese, and Chinese?

Tags: fonts, languages, unicode, cjk

I'm writing a document which is 99% English but needs a few words of other languages, including Thai, Japanese, and Chinese. I've had success with the latter two, but I'm stuck on Thai. Here's a MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

Japanese: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}結核\end{CJK}
Chinese: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}結核\end{CJK}
Thai: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gar}ไข้เด็งกี\end{CJK}   % <-- fail 

\end{document}
```

Compiling this fails with:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `C70/gar/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `C70/song/m/n' instead on input line 9.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/c70song.fd)
./b0rken.tex:9: Undefined control sequence.
try@size@range ...extract@rangefontinfo font@info 
                                                  <-*>@nil <@nnil 
l.9 Thai: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gar}ไข
                                      ้เด็งกี\end{CJK}  % <-- ...
```

Commenting out the "fail" line leads to successful compile with Japanese and Chinese characters where they should be in the output.

This is using MacTeX 2013. I do have the `cjk` and `fonts-tlwg` packages installed. I also have several `c90*` files present, including `c90gar.fd`
and `c90nrsr.fd`.

I do need to stay with normal pdfTeX rather than XeTeX.

Comment: There's no CJK fonts in `C70` encoding (Unicode) preinstalled for Thai in TeX Live. Fonts in `C90` encoding cannot be used like that.

Comment: @Leo: OK. How can they be used? Are there `C70` fonts I can install?

Comment: The easiest way to use a few Thai words in LaTeX, is to include a graphic. I am not an expert on Thai. But the fonts for Thai are usually used in TIS 620 (input) encoding. Anyway, I'll try to provide a solution to explain how to use Thai fonts in `C90` (font) encoding installed in TeX Live.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use Thai fonts, we do not need to load `CJK` package, but `babel` package.

To use the fonts in `C90` encoding, we can use `thaicjk` option of `babel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% English is the main language
\usepackage[thaicjk,english]{babel}
\addto\extrasthaicjk{\fontencoding{C90}\selectfont}

% Hack into CJKutf8 package for an option clash error
\makeatletter
\@namedef{opt@inputenc.sty}{utf8}
\makeatother
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

Japanese: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}結核\end{CJK}
Chinese: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}結核\end{CJK}
Thai: \foreignlanguage{thaicjk}{ไข้เด็งกี}

\end{document}
```

Or, we can also use the fonts in `LTH` encoding. In this case we need to use `thai` option of babel.  See document of [`babel-thai`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/thai/thai.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% English is the main language
\usepackage[thai,english]{babel}

% Hack into CJKutf8 package for an option clash error
\makeatletter
\@namedef{opt@inputenc.sty}{utf8}
\makeatother
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

Japanese: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}結核\end{CJK}
Chinese: \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}結核\end{CJK}
Thai: \textthai{ไข้เด็งกี}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The second example works for me, thank you. (I didn't try the first.)