# Korean characters in article title

Tags: fonts, pdftex, cjk

I'm writing a paper in English and need to include a few characters in Korean in the body and title.  I've read several other posts and managed to get the Hangul to show up inside the body, but I can't get them to show up inside the title.  I am using pdflatex and have all of the necessary fonts installed.

Here's the minimum working example that shows the characters appearing in the body but not in the title on my system:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[thai,english]{babel}
\addto\extrasthaicjk{\fontencoding{C90}\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{opt@inputenc.sty}{utf8}
\makeatother
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\newenvironment{Korean}{%
  \CJKfamily{mj}}{}

\title{
  Character does not show up here:
   \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}\begin{Korean}시험\end{Korean}\end{CJK}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

It works here  \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}\begin{Korean}시험\end{Korean}\end{CJK}    

\end{document}
```

I don't see any errors about the title, so I'm stuck on what to do.  This is my first time including foreign script characters in a LaTeX, so any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need `utf8x`? I believe it's simply better to use `utf8` (this avoids the disputable `opt@inputenc.sty`  trick).

Comment: @egreg: The code is from my [previous answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145299/2674). `utf8x` is needed for Thai language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original document, if you put your `\title` command after `\begin{document}` things work.  However, if you don't load the `inputenc` package at all, things also work. I think this is a better solution.  I've added the `fontenc` package to use the T1 encoding for the Latin text and removed the trick that @egreg mentions in his comment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newcommand\textkorean[1]{%
  \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}#1\end{CJK}}

\title{
   Character now shows up here:
   \textkorean{시험}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

It works here \textkorean{시험}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!  This solves the problem exactly.  I hadn't thought of repositioning the \title due to CJK's preprocessing.

Comment: @DavidJurgens See my updated answer.  This is not the source of the problem.

Comment: We don't need to load `thai` option for `babel` if Thai support is not needed. And the code needs to be clean up.

Comment: Thai was actually needed in my example, as I was using both Thai and Korean for the article.  The Thai script worked as expected but the problem was getting Korean script in the title.